# Protractor invisibilityOf flakiness, throwing NoSuchElementError

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, protractor

I am testing a **non angular** app using protractor where I have a login helper function in my tests similar to the following:

```
function login() {
        return waitUntilVisible($('#txtUsername'))
            .then(function () {
                $('#txtUsername').sendKeys('tom');
            })
            .then(function () {
                $('#txtPassword').sendKeys('*');
            })
            .then(function () {
                $('#btnLogin').click();
            })
            .then(function () {
                // this is the flaky line
                return browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf($('#txtUsername')), 20000, 'Element never disappeared');
            });
    }
```

Where `browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf($('#txtUsername')), 20000, 'Element never disappeared')` waits for a bootstrap modal containing the login form to close. However, this line is proving to be very flaky, occasionally failing with:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("#txtUsername")

Or even:

> StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

My first though was that the modal was closing before the line was called, however, the docs for `invisibilityOf` suggest it should handle the element not being present, stating it as:

> An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.

**How can I make this line robust?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from `invisibilityOf` to `stalenessOf` has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `visibilityOf` or `textToBePresentInElement` are not atomic and can produce errors. Internally they check `isPresent` and `isDisplayed`/`getText` sequentially, but if a element is removed exactly between these checks a `NoSuchElementError` or a `StaleElementReferenceError` will occur.

This bug might be fixed in a future version. Before you can use a workaround I wrapped as npm module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-save-expected-conditions